# limit of an annoying definite integral

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

I would like to prove the following:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x\left(\frac{x}{t}-1\right)^{1/2}\;dt=\infty$$

It might not be true.

I suppose I could try to give a lower bound via Riemann sums, and hope they tend to something order larger than x. But it seems like there should be an easier way.

Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It's not true.** Let $x>0$; and do the change of variable $u=t/x$. The integral becomes
$$
\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x \left(\frac{x}{t}-1\right)^{1/2} dt
= \int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{u}-1\right)^{1/2} du = \frac{\pi}{2}
$$
independent of $x$. (The value matters little; but it's finite, and *independent of $x$*.)

---

To see that the integral is finite (i.e., $f(u)=\left(\frac{1}{u}-1\right)^{1/2}$ is integrable on $(0,1]$), note that $f$ is continuous on $(0,1]$ *(therefore, the only question is integrability at $0$)*, and moreover
$$
f(u) \operatorname*{\sim}_{u\to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}
$$
so by comparison $f$ is integrable at $0$, since $1/\sqrt{u}$ is.